# How to implement newline from firestore database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, textview, google-cloud-firestore

I've a football team in a string field in my Firestore database. I have a `TextView` in my app that shows the data from the field. I want to jump to a newline after each player. When the team is stored as a string in the strings.xml file, the characters \n signify the end of a line and the start of a new one. \n doesn't work with Firestore. I've tried storing the data in a string before evoking setText but this doesn't make any difference. How do I get to move to the next line in my `TextView`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so instead of putting \n in my team string between each player, I put "bb" (any string will do) between them and stored it in firestore. Then I used

```
  String temp1= temp.replace("bb", "\n");
```

before invoking setText on the TextView. Worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore add this type----Line one\nline two\nline three

get Sting, replace and show with TextView

String sura=receivedString.replace( "\n", "\n");

Working..